# sudoku problema com linhas/colunas repetidas

Tags: c, jogos

*Bom eu estou fazendo um trabalho de faculdade que é fazer um sudoku no qual o PC joga, primeiramente eu estou criando as regras do jogo que é nenhum número pode ser repetido na linha nem na fileira onde ele esta...*

Como todos sabem o sudoku inicia com alguns números então eu coloquei eles usando o **srand+rand()%x** e alguns números acabam se repetindo...

Outro problema que estou tendo é com os outros espaço eu gostaria de saber o que eu faço para não aparecer nada... eu coloco **NULL** e ai como estou usando inteiros aparece o numero 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int su[9][9];
    int i, j;
    int cont;

    srand( (unsigned)time(NULL) );//evita que o rand seja gerado pelo tempo

    for(i=0; i<9; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<9; j++)
        {
            cont=rand()%9;

            if(i==cont || j==cont)
                su[i][j]=1+rand()%9;
            else
            {
                su[i][j]=NULL;
            }
            if( su[i][j]==su[i+1][j+1])
            {
                su[i][j]=NULL;
            }
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<9; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<9; j++)
        {
            printf("[%i]", su[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    /*for(i=1 ; i <= 10 ; i++)
        printf("Numero %d: %d\n",i, 1+rand()%9);*/


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Procure separar melhor o texto, com ele todo amontoado fica difícil ler e entender o problema. O título não descreve sucintamente o problema. Talvez porque tenha mais de um problema na pergunta.

Comment: Editei a sua pergunta, como disse o @bigown, separei o texto e pus um título que descreve o problema. Numa próxima já saberá melhor o que fazer. Sinta-se a vontade de editar a sua pergunta se achar pertinente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como é lógico tens de verificar ao inserir um valor se ele já existe na mesma linha e na mesma coluna antes de inserir. Para isso criei a função `isValueInLineOrColumn` que verifica se já existe ou não o valor na linha/coluna.

Quanto ao `NULL` o melhor mesmo é usares o zero como indicador de quadrado vazio e imprimires um quadrado vazio.

Defini ainda o N com valor 9 para que possas alterar o máximo de quadrados sem ter de mexer no código.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define N 9

int isValueInLineOrColumn(int val, int arr[N][N], int line, int column)
{
    int i,j;

    for (i=0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if(arr[line][i] == val)
            return 1;

        if (arr[i][column] == val)
            return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int su[N][N];
    int i, j;
    int cont;

    srand( (unsigned)time(NULL) );//evita que o rand seja gerado pelo tempo

    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<N; j++)
        {
            cont=rand()%N;

            if(i==cont || j==cont)
            {

                int val = 1+rand()%N;

                //verifica se já existe este valor na linha ou coluna atual.
                if(isValueInLineOrColumn(val, su, i, j))
                    su[i][j]=0;
                else
                    su[i][j]=val;

            }
            else
            {
                //usando 0 como identificador de vazio
                su[i][j]=0;
            }
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<N; j++)
        {
            if(su[i][j]!=0)
                printf("[%i]", su[i][j]);
            else
                printf("[ ]");//se for igual a 0 coloca o quadrado vazio.
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    /*for(i=1 ; i <= 10 ; i++)
        printf("Numero %d: %d\n",i, 1+rand()%9);*/


    return 0;
}
```

**Um dos resultados:**

```
[5][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][3][ ]
[ ][7][ ][ ][9][ ][ ][1][ ]
[6][ ][4][ ][ ][ ][1][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][2][6][ ][ ][4][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][5][ ][ ]
[ ][3][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
```

**[Exemplo online](http://ideone.com/ld7TZl)**

Comment: cara eu mudei o modelo ja que é o pc que vai jogar eu vou mecher com FILE e arquivo.txt e colocar as regras =) qualquer duvida eu vejo o seu como referencia =0 muito obrigado

Comment: oi @Jorge B. gostaria de manter contato com o senhor.